# Pub/sub push subscription to an endpoint API URL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-platform

Since it is mandatory to register non app-engine endpoints as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#other-endpoints),I can't register my endpoint and it shows the error: Invalid property URL; please specify a site or directory URL, not a page URL.[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RFSa.png)

What can be the alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have:

- A HTTPS server.
- A valid SSL certificate.
- Register the endpoint domain with the GCP project.
- Register the **https://** version of your site URL.

> **[Configuring HTTP Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#configuring-http-endpoints)**
>
> You need a publicly accessible HTTPS server to handle POST requests in order to receive push messages. The server must present a valid SSL certificate signed by a certificate authority and routable by DNS. You also need to validate that you own the domain (or have equivalent access to the endpoint). Finally, you must register the endpoint domain with the GCP project. Note that these steps are considerably simplified on App Engine, where SSL certificates are provided and verification requirements can be relaxed.
>
> **[Step 1: Verify you have access to the domain](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#other-endpoints)**
>
> Complete the site verification process using Search Console. Be sure to register the https:// version of your site URL. For more details, see the site verification help documentation.